# HTC Sensation framebuffer (dev/graphics/fb0) screenshot scrambled image

Tags: android, htc-android

Could some one tell me why I get scrambled screenshots from the HTC Sensation?

Here's what I'm doing:

```
adb pull /dev/graphics/fb0 fb0
ffmpeg -vframes 1 -vcodec rawvideo -f rawvideo -pix_fmt rgb32 -s 540x960 -i fb0 -f image2 -vcodec png image.png
```

Comment: Can you provide ffmpeg output?

Answer (score 2):

I'm using HTC sensation HD, the code below works fine for me.

```
ffmpeg -vframes 1 -vcodec rawvideo -f rawvideo -pix_fmt bgr32 -s 480x800  -i fb0 -f image2 -vcodec png image2.png
```

You are using RGB32 format, you have to use BGR32.